# How can I implement global hot key in Python .app on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, hotkeys

I'm currently modifying an app that was written by someone within my organization that no longer is able to maintain it. I am attempting to implement a system-wide global hot key that will simply bring the app window into focus when pressed.

The only implementation of this I came across online was through PyObjC in their HotKeyPython example. That example uses Carbon though, and did not appear to function at all when I was testing it.

Here's what I was trying which did not appear to work:

```
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *
from Carbon.CarbonEvt import RegisterEventHotKey
from Carbon.Events import cmdKey, controlKey, optionKey, shiftKey
import objc, AppLauncher
import platform
import struct
IS_SNOW_LEOPARD = platform.mac_ver()[0].startswith('10.6')
if IS_SNOW_LEOPARD:
  from Quartz import *

kEventHotKeyPressedSubtype = 6
kEventHotKeyReleasedSubtype = 9


class AppLauncher(NSObject):
  window = objc.IBOutlet()
  view = objc.IBOutlet()
  field = objc.IBOutlet()


  def awakeFromNib(self):
    self.window.makeFirstResponder_(self.field)
    self.field.selectText_(self)
    self.field.setDelegate_(self)
    self.controlTextDidChange_(None)

    def applicationDidFinishLaunching(self):
        # register cmd-control-J
        self.hotKeyRef = RegisterEventHotKey(38, cmdKey + controlKey, (0, 0),
                                             sendEvent_(), 0)

    def sendEvent_(self, theEvent):
        if theEvent.type() == NSSystemDefined and \
               theEvent.subtype() == kEventHotKeyPressedSubtype:
            self.activateIgnoringOtherApps_(True)
            NSRunAlertPanel(u'Hot Key Pressed', u'Hot Key Pressed',
                None, None, None)
        super(AppLauncher, self).sendEvent_(theEvent)
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working (preferably without getting Carbon involved)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In what way did it not work?  For example, are you sure that all of the functions above are actually called?  Are any exceptions raised?  Is there any chance that the chosen key is already in use by another application?